# Serializing a mock throws exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, gson, mockito

I am trying to test my controller using mockMvc and mockito. The actual controller body is as following :

```
Message createXYZ(@RequestBody XYZ inst){
   //creates XYZ
}
```

Now for pushing the values via request body, I am creating a JSON using GsonBuilder by serializing XYZ. Here is the structure for class XYZ :

```
class XYZ{

  List<Y> listofYs;
  //some other properties as well
}
```

I am creating and setting a mock for List listofYs and when Gson is trying to serialize an instance of XYZ that has a mocked listofYs its generating NPE.

Is there a way around or is it that I am doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 19):

According to [the Mockito documentation](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#serializable--), you can make a mock serializable:

```
List serializableMock = mock(List.class, withSettings().serializable());
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, I am getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Expecting parameterized type, got interface org.mockito.internal.MockitoInvocationHandler.
 Are you missing the use of TypeToken idiom?

as the stacktrace

Comment: Well, what does your source code look like now? Also: Do you actually _need_ to mock the list for verifying interaction with it? If this is not about verifying interaction, the easiest solution would be to just use an actual, serializable list.

Comment: Actually yes I wanted to verify the interactions. But now I am using fakes for that purpose but still I am loosing the verifying the behavior and interactions part. :(

Answer (score 9):

Similarly to [Stefan's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24191600/729819), mocks created via annotations can be marked as serializable through:

```
@Mock(serializable = true)
List serializableMock;
```